# Proof that two sets have the same cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let J be the set of all even finite subsets of a set M, and U the set of the odd. Show that J and U have the same cardinality.

To tell the truth, I haven't gotten far. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: If $M=\varnothing$ that's false.

Comment: "of the odd"?${}$

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you define better? Is $M$ finite or infinite ? What do you mean by "the odd"? finite subsets of odd size ?If $M$ is finite the result is false.

Comment: I hoped you would know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $M$ is infinite, you can prove the result by showing that both $J$ and $U$ have same cardinality as $M$. This is because you have injections $J,U\to \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}M^k$, each $M^k$ has same cardinality as $M$, and countable union preserves all infinite cardinals.
So $J$ and $U$ are at most cardinality of $M$.

The other direction is simpler: there is an injection $M\to U$ (and $M\to J$) just using singletons.